# Is sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV can do custom threshold?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My goal is to do threshold tuning before parameter tuning. The idea is simple, in imbalanced dataset, if class 1 is minority, then the threshold should be lower than 0.5, so it predict more instance as class 1 instead of 0.

Therefore, I believe, by changing the threshold early, we can improve the model predictive power even more than (parameter tuning - threshold tuning).

The problem is, I don't find the parameter in GridSearchCV to change the threshold.

Comment: Don't rely on accuracy for an imbalanced dataset, rather look into balanced accuracy or just use recall and/or precision. What you are describing is more of an if else, rather than trying to find a threshold parameter in GS.

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus I use f2 score for this. I want to tell GridSearchCV to use predict_proba instead of predict or whatever GridSearchCV use that I believe is using threshold 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly change the threshold used by `predict` (which gets called by your scorer, presumably), but you can provide a customer `scoring` method.  See [the User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring).  Here I think you'd want something like:

```py
def f2_score_at_thresh(y_true, y_pos_prob, threshold):
    y_pred = y_pos_prob > threshold
    return fbeta_score(y_true, y_pred, beta=2, ...)

my_scorer = make_scorer(f2_scorer, needs_proba=True, threshold=0.2)

GridSearchCV(..., scoring=my_scorer)
```

Comment: My God. The concept is valid. I will try this when I have the chance to go back to sklearn.